# Connecting ODBC progress with sql azure

Tags: sql, azure, odbc, openedge, progress-db

Somehow I cannot find it anywhere on the internet. Currently we are running an on premise version of SQL Server. We are looking for the possibility to migrate to the azure cloud for our databases.

However one of our databases heavly runs query using an openedge odbc linked server solution to query an progress database.

I cannot find if it is possible to create a linked server in the azure cloud to allow connections to that progress database.

Does anyone knows if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Azure SQL Database Managed Instance only support SQL Server/SQL Database linked Servers, Single Database and Elastic pool doesn't support linked servers.
You may check the features that supported by Azure SQL Database here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features